# JAVA ENV issue in dev box

Tags: java

We have multiple java version installed in our dev box. I get errors run one program to one java version to other version. What is going out here and how I can fix this.

```
> java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260sr16fp55-20171123_01(SR16 FP55))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32 jvmap3260sr16fp55-20171016_367398 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20171016_367398
JIT  - r9_20171016_367398
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20171016_1318_B367398)
JCL  - 20171109_01
jdoe@devbox-DN1 - /home/jdoe

> java helloworld
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: helloworld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helloworld
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:457)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
Could not find the main class: helloworld.  Program will exit.*

> java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3270sr10fp60-20200113_02(SR10 FP60))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 AIX ppc-32 20191221_435663 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR10_20191221_0017_B435663
JIT  - r11_20191221_435663
GC   - R26_Java726_SR10_20191221_0017_B435663
J9CL - 20191221_435663)
JCL - 20200110_01 based on Oracle jdk7u251-b07
jdoe@devbox- - /home/jdoe

> java helloworld
Hello World!
jdoe@devbox- - /home/jdoe

> cat hw.java
/* Hello World Java Program */
class helloworld  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename `hw.java` to `helloworld.java`. Also change your `class helloworld` to `public class helloworld`.

Comment: Note: you could create shell-scripts to simplify using different java-versions paralelly, eg `javac7` would be `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java71; export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"; exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac" "$@"`

Comment: Is CLASSPATH plays any role here ?

Comment: Unlikely: your program doesn't have dependencies other than the built-in ones.